# Good reference on the parametrization of $SU(3)$ and $SU(N)$

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, lie-algebra, representation-theory

For the 2-dimensional $SU(2)$ matrices, there is a fairly general parametrization formulation:

$s_2=\begin{bmatrix}
    e^{i\alpha}\cos(\theta) & -e^{-i\beta}\sin(\theta) \\
    e^{i\beta}\sin(\theta) & e^{-i\alpha}\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$

For the 3-dimension $SU(3)$ and the higher-dimension $SU(N)$ matrices, what are the most general parametrization formulations? I will appreciate any references, either a book or a review paper, on this subject oriented toward the physics/engineer applications.

EDIT:

This is to clarify my question and make it more relevant to the physics. I am looking for the kind of parametrization that is generally applicable to the problems in physics, especially being intuitive and geometrically accessible. For example, for the $SU(2)$ matrices given above, $\theta$ parameterizes the coefficients of any orthonormal states, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameterize the phases of the orthonormal states. The orthonormal states in this kind of general expression are certainly very common and relevant to enormous problems in quantum physics.

Comment: Are you asking for *unique* parametrizations? Otherwise, can't you just go with $e^{\theta_i T_i}$ where $T_i$ are the $N^2-1$ generators of the algebra?

Comment: I don't think the parametrization would be unique. I guess I am looking for the kind of parametrization that will make the most physical sense. For example, in the case of the $SU(2)$, the $\theta$ parameterizes the orthonormal coefficients, while the $\alpha$ and the $\beta$ parameterize phase angles. Anything along that line would be helpful.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be about physics. (That the groups $\mathrm{SU}(N)$ are used in physics doesn't make it about physics anymore than questions about addition are about physics because physicists often add things)

Comment: @ACuriousMind I am asking about the kind of parametrization that specifically makes physical sense, and generally applicable to the problems in physics.

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0034-4877(15)30040-9).

Comment: @FosterBoondoggle But for high degree, even relative degree such as $SU(4)$, the using parametrization method like $e^{\theta_iT_i}$ cannot easily be written as matrix form since $[T_i,T_j]\neq0$ generally. So if we want to find matrix parametrization method, this is not a good way right?

Comment: @narip - I think it depends on your goal. You can certainly *write* an SU(N) matrix that way, even though the generators don't commute. The non-commutativity just makes it hard to invert the exponent.

Comment: @FosterBoondoggle I mean, let's say $SU(4)$ case, there are 15 parameters, writing $e^{\theta_i T_i}$ into matrix form with 15 parameters is so difficult(at least I think), so if we want to write into a matrix form, I don't think taking parameters from exponential form into matrix form is a good way?

Answer (score 2):

For SU(3) there is a parametrization with trigonometric functions similar to the one you have written for SU(2), described in http://journals.aps.org/prd/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevD.38.1994.

[image: Matrix elements are:]

However, I think it is better to work with the $exp^{i\theta_i T_i}$ formula, where $T_i$s are the generators of the group in the appropriate representation.

Comment: This is behind a paywall, so many users will not be able to see the result. Despite this, link-only answers are discouraged. Maybe you can add the relevant passages to the post?

Comment: J Bronzan [1994](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.38.1994). Google scholar makes them available for free.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that what you're asking for is the $e^{\theta_i T_i}$ representation. The $T_i$'s are the equivalent of the Pauli matrices except $N\times N$ dimensional in the fundamental rep. (I might be missing a factor of $i$.)

It's not clear what you mean by "physical sense" in your comment above. For describing rotations uniquely in 3-d. for example, your fundamental representation of $SU(2)$ is probably less useful than the adjoint one where the isomorphism to SO(3) is more apparent. For doing $SU(3)$ QCD calcs, I don't recall ever paying attention to details of *how* the representation was parameterized. What mattered was things like the structure constants of the commutators.

Comment: See [this one](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0034-4877(15)30040-9).

Answer (score 1):

A possible parametrization for a real transformation matrix is via the [Cayley transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform): an orthogonal (i.e., real unitary) matrix can be represented as
$$
Q=(I-A)(I+A)^{-1},
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $A$ is skew-symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

There's [this](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.528890) article by Adam Bincer,  published in *Journal of Mathematical Physics*, vol 31 (1990). It is titled *Parametrisation of SU(n) with n-1 orthonormal vectors* and it's abstract states:

> A generalisation to SU(n) of a well-known relation to SU(2) is proposed. It relies on the observation that an element of SU(n) has associated with it in a natural way n-1 orthonormal vectors in $R^{n^2-1}$. The meaning of these n-1 vectors is discussed as they relate to the geometry of the adjoint representation of SU(n).

Unfortunately, although it is now published online, it's not public access, so I can't say more.