# Parameterization of $SU(4)$

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I'm looking for a parameterization or general form for a $4\times 4$ special unitary matrix in closed form. I have looked at the answer to [Good reference on the parametrization of $SU(3)$ and $SU(N)$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/237988/) but it did not lead me to an answer (there is a paper linked that I cannot access, though I'm unsure if the answer is in there). The answer by fermion for $SU(3)$ in that thread is what I'm looking for, but for $SU(4)$. In other words, I'm looking for $S: \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow SU(4)$.

I have found this paper: http://www.ejtp.com/articles/ejtpv10i28p9.pdf that lists the generators of $SU(4)$, though I'm unsure how to use this for what I'm looking for.

For some more context, I need to be able to compute $S$ reasonably quickly, so descriptions using matrix exponentiation are not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest

> de Guise H, Di Matteo O, Sánchez-Soto LL. Simple factorization of unitary transformations. Physical review A. 2018 Feb 20;97(2):022328,

with arXiv version https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00735.

They give a parameterization of $SU(4)$ (and $SU(N)$) in terms of consecutive $SU(2)$ transformations acting on different subspaces.  Thus the transformations can easily be constructed from $SU(2)$ matrices.  Figure 2 gives the explicit scheme for $SU(4)$.

The paper also discusses the Haar measure in this factorization and there’s a Python code available from Ref.[44] to give you the angles starting from any $SU(N)$ matrix.

It’s not exactly the $SU(4)$ version of the answer you like but it’s ready-made.  It’s not the only possible parameterization (as can be seen from the text and the bibliography) but it’s easy to implement as it’s just a matter of placing the same type of $2\times 2$ boxes inside a larger matrix.

Comment: Can this be easily written into relatively simple matrix form? It seems that the point of the paper is to show how it can be parametrized by the multiplication of a lot of $SU(2)$ matrices. Is there some method that can simply give relatively matrix parametrization such as for $SU(2)$ we can have $\left( \begin{matrix}
 \alpha&  -\bar{\beta}\\
 \beta&  \bar{\alpha}\\
\end{matrix} \right) $ or $cos\theta I+sin\theta \sigma _{\vec{n}}$, thanks!

Comment: @narip I do not know if it is possible but this would defeat the purpose of this paper since the entire point is to write the transformations recursively in terms of embedded $SU(2)$ blocks.